# Angular ng-model is undefined in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

This is my code

HTML:

```
<div class="someClass">
  <label>Enter Text Here:</label>
  <textarea id="content-editable" ng-model="myTextArea" ng-keyup="callme($event)">
  </textarea>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var text = $scope.myTextArea.text
```

I am getting an exception in JS that "cannot find property text of undefined".

I am not sure if text property is needed to get the text from textarea but I am getting undefined in debugger for `$scope.myTextArea`

Whats wrong?

Comment: have you assigned `$scope.myTextArea = { text : 'abc' }` in your controller somewhere ?

Answer (score 2):

Data binding require just to refer `$scopel.myTextArea` and you don't need to do `.text` - see demo below:

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.callme = function(event) {
    console.log($scope.myTextArea);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="someClass" ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <label>Enter Text Here:</label>
  <textarea id="content-editable" ng-model="myTextArea" ng-keyup="callme($event)">
  </textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `.text` cz it'll by default give you the value.

just use like this

```
var text = $scope.myTextArea;
```